# Returning a response object from HTTP methods in Class based Views

Tags: django

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

        if not allow_empty:
            # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
            # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
            # queryset in memory.
            if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
                is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
            else:
                is_empty = not self.object_list
            if is_empty:
                raise Http404(_('Empty list and “%(class_name)s.allow_empty” is False.') % {
                    'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
                })
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

So i've taken this code from the docs, im interested in the render_to_response() method, i have 
read around and i believe it constructs an instance of a some specified Response class (templateReponseMixin.response_class attribute) or default Response class(TemplateResponse class), could someone more experienced than me tell me whether the Response instance is also rendered within the render_to_response() method and returned or would it be rendered by another middleware code?

Answer (score 0):

Two things related with your question:

1. Seems you forgot to pass a template to this method. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) is the signature. And yes, it will render the template by calling [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/shortcuts/#render) of the [template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/template/loader/) module. Basically the only difference is that `render` is passing the `request` object into template context and this method is not.
2. If you starting project from scratch, I think you may not bother yourself with render_to_response because it was deprecated since v2.0

Comment: i think there could be 2 render_to_response() methods

Comment: TemplateResponseMixin¶
class django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin¶

Comment: Yes, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin). I mean that it's no longer available in shortcuts module.

Comment: Yes but there one in teh question doesnt use the shortcuts version

Comment: What Django version is this? In newest (v3.0) version both [view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py) and [MultipleObjectMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/335c9c94acf263901fb023404408880245b0c4b4/django/views/generic/list.py) do not have this method, while [TemplateResponseMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2ea3fb3e6386c43f124b542e92b817dbc227c76b/django/views/generic/base.py) do have.

Comment: It is inherited from TemplateResponseMixin

Comment: It's not visible from the code you provided but anyway - let it be : )